# MFC button can not receive touch event

Tags: mfc, touch, mouse

the list control can receive the touch event, but the push button can not receive the touch event, it always receive the mouse move event.

I want to send the touch event to the button's parent, how to resole this?

code like below can tell if it is a mouse or touch event, but can not forward the event to its parent to handle the touch event.
    #define MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH 0xFF515700

```
if ((GetMessageExtraInfo() & MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH) == MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH) { 
// Click was generated by wisptis / Windows Touch
}else{ 
// Click was generated by the mouse.
}
```

by the way, how to stop converting touch event to mouse event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With WM_TOUCH/WM_GESTURE you get a handle to the touch input event list. The [TOUCHINPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317334%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) data isn't dedicated to a specific window. Different to [GESTUREINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd353232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But it shouldn't be complicated to translate the info.

An unhandled WM_GESTURE message passed to DefWindowProc will be propagated to the parent window. When forwarding gesture messages between windows, avoid sending messages from parent to child windows in order to prevent closed loops from occurring.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee220935.aspx

For a WM_TOUCH message you can use a user defined message and post this message with the lParam value to the parent of the button. **But you must handle this message there and need to call [CloseTouchInputHandle](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDMQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dd371423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx&ei=bAeCUpuqK4jItQajvoGQBg&usg=AFQjCNHlCYHH1OUthcMm26Dyj7v2MmJoqg&sig2=uWN5CEmbNZ8Kva06u4rSCw&bvm=bv.56146854,d.Yms&cad=rjt)**

If you don't pass the WM_TOUCH/WM_GESTURE message to DefWidnowProc no further translation is done.

Touch events are converted to mouse messages in the DefWindowProc processing.
What gestures are supported and converted to mouse messages is listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The list control can receive the touch event, but the push button or textedit can not receive the touch event, it always receive the mouse move event.

code like below can tell if it is a mouse or touch event, but when flick up & down for a while, it can not receive the event.

Then flick left & right can always receive the mouse move event

```
#define MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH 0xFF515700

if ((GetMessageExtraInfo() & MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH) == MOUSEEVENTF_FROMTOUCH) { 
// Click was generated by wisptis / Windows Touch
}else{ 
// Click was generated by the mouse.
}
```

I put this button in a scrollview which has the vertical scroll bar.